# How do I get two columns in part of my PDF document created from Quarto + Latex when working in RStudio?

Tags: multiple-columns, pdflatex, quarto

Pretty simple question: how do I get two columns for part of a document with Quarto?

In particular, a PDF document rendered using PDFlatex.  I am working on a Mac in RStudio and rendering via the "render" button.

Here's quarto source code:

```
---
format: pdf
---

Some heading text.

:::: {.columns}

::: {.column}
text in col1
:::

::: {.column}
text in col2
:::

::::

Some bottom text.
```

Which renders to this:

[image: reprex]

It may be helpful to note that changing "pdf" to "html" in the yaml header and re-rendering yields a two-column result:

[image: repres_html]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "native" quarto solution is to use `{layout}` instead of `{.columns}`according to [this quarto-dev discussion](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/4959#discussioncomment-5428704):

```
---
format: pdf
---

Some heading text.

:::: {layout="[0.5, 0.5]"}

:::{#firstcol}
text in col1
:::

:::{#secondcol}
text in col2
:::

::::

Some bottom text.
```

Which renders to:

[image: a_pdf_file]

Comment: Cool! Hadn't run across this before.

Comment: It is also interesting that `{.columns}` is supported with the Beamer latex class, but not the article class.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a feature that is not supported natively by Quarto syntax yet, so we will have to revert to using LaTeX syntax to achieve this goal. I'd recommend [this](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multiple_columns) as a good start to understanding multiple column layouts in LaTeX. We will need the additional `multicol` LaTeX package in order to accomplish this. You can load this in Quarto with the following YAML options:

```
---
format: 
  pdf:
    include-in-header:
      - text: |
          \usepackage{multicol}
---
```

Then to use the columns in your document, do the following. I am creating a multicols environment, with 2 columns, and I break where one column ends with `\columnbreak`.

```
Some initial text at full width for quarto, this should go all the way across
the page

\begin{multicols}{2}

Here is the first column

\columnbreak

Here is the second column

\end{multicols}

Now let us go back to normal text length now that the multicols environment 
has ended.
```

This produces this effect:

[image]

Feel free to ask any additional questions, if this answer works well for you make sure to mark it as accepted for future users.

Comment: Thank you!  Upvoted for the excellent workaround.  I'll give it a minute to see if there's a more "native" quarto approach before marking as "accepted."

Comment: @DanY Great, glad it worked for you. Taking a look at this [documentation page](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/article-layout.html), it seems like Quarto may be a little bit vague about exactly what formatting options are only supported by HTML, but not by LaTeX. I'll be interested to see if you find anything additional on this.

Comment: Looks like this has been discussed on the [quarto-dev site](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/4959#discussioncomment-5428704) with a recommendation to use a "layout" div instead of "columns".  Interesting.  Would be nice to find this in the online documentation rather than buried in a bug report...